# MySQL Workbench support for json colums

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-workbench

I have the following error in MySQL Workbench:
[image]

My settings are set to mysql 5.7 version:
[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You looked at the right place, provided your SQL editor is from a model object, not from the SQL IDE. In the latter case the server you connect to decides what features are available.

However, JSON support has been added in 5.7.8 and hence the error checker complains if you only have a version below that (5.7 is the same as 5.7.0). We already recognized this situation and hence changed the version field from a selector to a free text field, which then allows to specify the release version as well. This change will be available with the next WB version.

Comment: I was having the same problem and this did not solve it for me. It seems WB supports JSON in the tab where it is connected to a database, but not in the modelling tab. When I try to put a stored proc with `json` types and use the `->>` operator, it tells me my procedure has a syntax error and does not include it when I forward engineer it.

Comment: see my answer below for how to update the version number setting for a previously-created model.

Answer (score 8):

I figured it out: the version number in the settings dialogue shown by the OP changes *only* the version for the live database side of the program. On the model side, each model has its own version setting under Model -> Model Options -> MySQL:
[image]

I inferred that because I created the model *before* I updated the version that my model retained the old version number, unchecked the inherit box, and changed the version - problem solved.

Comment: Thank you very much. you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

Edit -> Preferences...

❌Not working

[image]

Model -> Model Options...

⭕Working completely

[image]